# How to visualize the correlation of columns into regression alike charts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regression, seaborn, data-science

## Conditions

I have columns named, Shopping_Satisfaction and Rating_Accuracy

They both store a value of rating range from 1 to 5, as below

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

path = '/kaggle/input/amazon-consumer-behaviour-dataset/Amazon Customer Behavior Survey.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(path)
df.groupby(['Shopping_Satisfaction', 'Rating_Accuracy']).count()['age']
```

**Group By Results**

```
Shopping_Satisfaction  Rating_Accuracy
1                      1                   37
                       2                   47
                       3                   24
                       4                    6
                       5                    1
2                      1                   10
                       2                   92
                       3                   79
                       4                    9
                       5                    3
3                      1                   10
                       2                   34
                       3                  145
                       4                   18
                       5                    2
4                      1                    1
                       2                    5
                       3                   34
                       4                   21
                       5                    6
5                      2                    1
                       3                    5
                       4                    2
                       5                    9
Name: age, dtype: int64
```

They are likely correlated, with 51% of correlation

```
                        Shopping_Satisfaction   Rating_Accuracy
Shopping_Satisfaction   1.000000                0.514387
Rating_Accuracy         0.514387                1.000000
```

## Questions

How To Translate These Insights for a question

**More Shopping_Satisfaction = More Rating_Accuracy?**

OR

**More Shopping_Satisfaction != More Rating_Accuracy?**

I tried using Regression Plot, but it didn't work well

It looks like this

```
5    o   o   o   o   o
4    o   o   o   o   o
3    o   o   o   o   o
2    o   o   o   o   o
1    o   o   o   o   o
0    1   2   3   4   5
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use heatmap plot of correlation matrix

Assume 'corr' is your correlation matrix, then:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
corr_plot = sns.heatmap(corr, cmap="YlGnBu", annot=True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I did, I made a heatmap for the correlation.
Is there any visualization could be used? Or heatmap is just the best fit for this case?

Comment: Yes heatmap is a simple and powerful way to visualise the correlation. Other one is a simple regression plot between the two features, with one feature values on the x axis and other on the y-axis.

Comment: I used the regression plot, but the result is pretty weird.
I show the results on the post

Comment: heatmap is enough for visualising correlation